# GSON parsing to object

Tags: java, gson

I will be recieving JSON strings in the following format:

```
{ "type":"groups", "groups":[ {"group":"NAME"}, ...] }
```

How would one form an object so that the following would work.

```
MyClass p = gson.fromJson(jsonString, MyClass.class);
```

The part I'm stuck it is "{"group":"NAME"}". Would this be fixed by saving objects inside the an array? Example.

```
public class MyClass {

    private String type;
    private List<MyOtherClass> groups = new ArrayList<MyOtherClass>();

    //getter and setter methods

}
```

**Answer: Nesting objects in each other doh! Thanks you guys! Crystal clear now :D**

```
public class MyOtherClass {
    private String group;

    public String getGroup() {
        return group;
    }

    public void setGroup(String group) {
        this.group = group;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "group: "+group;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a POJO for the group:

```
public class MyOtherClass {

   @Expose
   private String group;

   public String getGroup() {
      return group;
   }

   public void setGroup(String group) {
      this.group = group;
   }
```

}

Next you need one for your 'MyClass', which would look like this:

```
public class MyClass {

    @Expose
    private String type;

    @Expose
    private List<MyOtherClass> groups = new ArrayList<MyOtherClass>();

    public String getType() {
       return type;
    }

    public void setType(String type) {
       this.type = type;
    }

    public List<Group> getGroups() {
       return groups;
    }

    public void setGroups(List<Group> groups) {
       this.groups = groups;
    }

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Note that OP's `MyClass` used a list of `MyOtherClass` objects, you created a `Group` object. It might be clearer to stick with OP's naming scheme.

Comment: @dimo414 true! He did give me a clear view of how everything works though :D

Comment: @dimo414 many thanks for the feedback, I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

At first glance, this looks fine, assuming `MyOtherClass` has a field called `group` that holds a String.  What do you mean by "the part I'm stuck [on]"?  Perhaps you could post the stack trace you're seeing, a broader description of what you're trying to do, or best of all a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)?

When using GSON, I find it easiest to implement the class structure I need, then let GSON generate the JSON data from that.  You certainly can go the other way (design class structure based on JSON data), but I think it's more confusing if you don't understand what GSON is trying to do.

Some pseduo-code:

```
Class MyClass
  String type
  List<MyOtherClass> groups

Class MyOtherClass
  String group
```

Looking at this we can easily see the JSON that will hold our serialized object will look like so:

```
{
  type: "...",
  groups: [
    { group: "..." },
    ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: I didnt hav ea clue how to get the array fixed, thanks! The private String group in MyOtherClass dide the trick :D